# The normalization results are not same

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mean, normalization

I am performing normalization on the random data. I calculated the mean and standard deviation of the data and normalizing by the formula Norm = (data - mean) / std, but I am not getting the result same as numpy normalization function gives and also I am not getting the bell shape curve.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

a = np.arange(-4, 4)

mean = sum(a/len(a))
std = (np.sqrt(sum((a-mean)**2)/(len(a)-1)))

y1 = norm.pdf(a, mean, std)
y2 = (a - mean) / std

print(y1)
print(y2)
```

output

```
y2 = [0.05868028 0.09674742 0.1350219  0.15950953 0.15950953 0.1350219
 0.09674742 0.05868028]

y1 = [-1.42886902 -1.02062073 -0.61237244 -0.20412415  0.20412415  0.61237244
  1.02062073  1.42886902]
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Put yet another way, adding this to your code will produce a value equal to `norm.pdf`:

```
pdf = np.exp(-y2*y2/2)/((2*np.pi)**0.5) / std
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm):

> Specifically, norm.pdf(x, loc, scale) is identically equivalent to
> norm.pdf(y) / scale with y = (x - loc) / scale.

So you're not comparing apples to apples: `y1` is equivalent to `(norm.pdf(y2) / std`:

```
assert (norm.pdf(y2) / std == y1).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we should have the same definition for normalization and standardization. You can learn more from this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70553/what-does-normalization-mean-and-how-to-verify-that-a-sample-or-a-distribution).

[image: term definition]

Then, the `y2` you calculate is the result of standardization or **z-score**. In order to calculate z-score with scipy, you should you `scipy.stats.zscore()` instead of `scipy.stats.norm.pdf()`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import zscore

a = np.arange(-4, 4)

y1 = (a - a.mean()) / a.std()
y2 = zscore(a)
```

`y1` and `y2` will be the same.